# Manually performing memory reallocation in c++ vectors

Tags: c++, memory, vector

[From this link](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-made-easier-how-vectors-grow/184401375), it says that there are four steps for memory reallocation when using c++ vectors...

1. Allocate enough memory for the desired new capacity;
2. Copy the elements from the old memory to the new;
3. Destroy the elements in the old memory;
4. and Deallocate the old memory.

I am particularly interested in numbers 3 and 4, is it possible to perform these tasks through code? Or does it just happen in the background.

I.e., am I able to "Destroy elements in memory" through code in C++? And am I able to directly "Deallocate memory" in C++ code?

Comment: honestly I didn't read the entire link but, regarding point 2: copying is not a good strategy unless the space after the end of the vector is already taken, then you have to do all the steps. If not you can just ask for more bytes and avoid point 2, 3 and 4. In pure you might use malloc, realloc and free. In c++ new and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I able to "Destroy elements in memory" through code in C++?

Yes. By calling the object's destructor. For example, if `x` is a reference to an object of type `T`, you can destroy that object with:

```
x.~T();
```

> And am I able to directly "Deallocate memory" in C++ code?

Of course. There are a variety of deallocation functions, that go with corresponding allocation functions. If you allocated with `malloc`, you deallocate with `free`. If you allocated with `operator new()`, you deallocate with `operator delete()`. If you allocated with `new char[]`, you deallocate with `delete[]`.

Comment: So in terms of a vector, I am guessing that malloc is called? So if you want to deallocate memory you use free?

Comment: @Ogen: For vector, it calls its allocator's `deallocate` function. If you just went with the default allocator (`std::allocator`), this means it calls [`operator delete(void*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, it should be "operator delete **[]** (void*)"

Comment: @Ogen: Wait, are you asking how to emulate what vector does (e.g. in your own vector-like class)? Or are you asking how to actually do these operations on a `std::vector`? Because if it's the latter, then you should not be doing that, as `std::vector` will do all this automatically.

Comment: @ixSci: For `std::allocator`? No it shouldn't.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, you mentioned `vector`, it should call the array version of the delete pair

Comment: @ixSci: `std::vector` handles its allocation and deallocation through its allocator. The default allocator for `std::vector` is `std::allocator`. `std::allocator::deallocate` calls `operator delete(void*)`, not `operator delete[](void*)`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yes my bad, sorry.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was asking the latter. I'm aware that vector does it automatically but I was just wondering if it **could** be done manually. And apparently it can

Comment: @Ogen: It can't be done manually **on a `std::vector`** without undefined behavior. But it can be done manually on memory which you have complete control over.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and yes! You might want to look into either the `std::allocator` type, or into placement new, `operator new`, destructor calls, and `operator delete`. (Note that operator new and operator delete are names of allocation and deallocation functions and not the same as the new and delete operators).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple STL functions for this..

- you could use the `vector::erase` member function to remove a single element or a range of elements from your vector,

  ```
  iterator erase (const_iterator position);
  iterator erase (const_iterator first, const_iterator last);
  ```
- and then, under C++11, call `vector::shrink_to_fit` to request the container to reduce it's capacity to exactly it's current size. (Note that the implementation is free to ignore this request though..)

  ```
      void shrink_to_fit();
  ```

  or use `vector::resize`

  ```
  void resize (size_type n);
  void resize (size_type n, const value_type& val);
  ```

For something like:

```
myVector.erase(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + 3);
myVector.shrink_to_fit();
```

Or

```
myVector.erase(myVector.begin(), myVector.begin() + 3);
resize(myVector.size());
```

*If you resize to a smaller size than the actual one - let's say your vector has 10 elements and you resize to a size_t = 7, after this your vector will only have the first 7 elements, the rest of them will be destroyed.

Also, if you want only some specific elements to be destroyed you could use the `Erase-remove idiom` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom and then `shrink_to_fit()` or `resize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's both possible and even required to both destroy and deallocate data in C++.

Generally there are two possible places where data can live in C++:

1. The stack, which is automatically managed, and
2. the heap, where you're responsible for deleting data that is no longer needed.

.

```
 void fn(void) {
   Data data;
 }
```

In a function like above, as soon as the function is called, there will be reserved some space in the stack for the variable data. Then it's constructor will be called, which could do additional setup (you can write them yourself and do literally anything). On function return first the destructor (that you also can and sometimes have to implement yourself) is called before the space occupied on the stack is freed by moving the stack pointer. All of this happens automatic.

```
void fn2(void) {
  Data * dataptr;
  dataptr = new Data();
  delete dataptr;
}
```

In this function the same as above is happening, only with a pointer, which you can think of as being an integer describing some location on memory. (And only in theory, since pointers like this have no constructor or destructor)

But then there's also the second and third line: Here I'm allocating and constructing a Data instance in the heap, and destruct and free it right afterwards. But I don't have to do it right there. I could store the pointer and use it to later access the instance, long after the function has returned.

All of this is wrapped inside classes like vector, to provide the same convenience as in managed languages, only that you can use it only when needed and aren't forced to use it.

As an example, here is a toy vector, only showing the part of resource management:

```
struct vec {
  size_t size;
  int * values;
  vec() {
    // constructor, may do anything here
    size = 0;
    values = nullptr;
  }
  free() {
    if (values != nullptr) {
      delete [] values;
    }
  }
  void push_back(int v) {
    // allocating new memory
    int * newvalues = new int[size + 1];
    // copy existing values
    for (size_t it = 0; it < size; ++it) {
      newvalues[it] = values[it];
    }
    // delete original values
    free ();
    // add new value at the now free spot
    newvalues[size] = v;
    ++size;
    // update the pointer to point to the new memory
    values = newvalues;
  }
  ~vec() {
    // destructor, may do anything here
    free();
  }
};
```

Just to say it again: This is toy code yo illustrate the general idea, for real code there's much more to consider.

As a final note: Above deallocating the memory and destructing always have been performed together. This is almost every time what you need. But you can also call a destructor manually:

```
Data data;
// ...
data.~Data();
```

The same is true for allocating and constructing instances. Having some memory one can use placement new to call the constructor.

Moreover, constructors and destructors are not only about managing memory, they could also help with open files, currently playing music or just about everything that needs initialisation and finalisation.

I hope this quick and rough tour helps you to understand the basic concept. I left out a lot of stuff and weren't precise at some points, so use this only as basis for further research